# How Can I Display Parent-Child-GrandChild Relationship Without using With Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My table Structure like this:

```
Id  Name    Parent
1   A-1 0
2   B-1 0
3   A-11    1
4   A-12    1
5   A-13    1
6   A-14    1
7   A-111   3
8   A-112   3
9   A-113   3
10  A-114   3
11  B-11    2
12  B-12    2
13  B-13    2
14  B-14    2
15  B-111   11
16  B-112   11
17  B-113   11
18  B-114   11
```

I want Display Like

```
Id  Name    Parent  GrandParentName
1   A-1     0   
2   B-1     0   
3   A-11    1   
4   A-12    1   
5   A-13    1   
6   A-14    1   
7   A-111   3   A-1
8   A-112   3   A-1
9   A-113   3   A-1
10  A-114   3   A-1
11  B-11    2   
12  B-12    2   
13  B-13    2   
14  B-14    2   
15  B-111   11  B-1
16  B-112   11  B-1
17  B-113   11  B-1
18  B-114   11  B-1
```

Without using With Clause and Inner Query ?

Comment: And why don't you want to use a common table expression (aka "with clause")? That's the perfect solution for that problem.

Comment: I want to do  using simple query using with clause we can do.

Comment: You can't do it without a recursive query. And the only way to do a recursive query is to use a CTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well can't say that I like it (it's not generalizable, using fixed joins), but if you want only GrandParent names, you can do it with 2 joins:

```
select T.Id, T.Name, T.Parent, G.Name as GrandParentName
from Table1 as T
    left outer join Table1 as P on P.Id = T.Parent
    left outer join Table1 as G on G.Id = P.Parent
order by T.Id asc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dc7b4/2)</kbd>**